# NSStatusItem and white highlighted image

Tags: cocoa

I create Status item with a black and transparent PNG. 
I see that many applications change color icon to white when highlighted (with the default blue background) i wondering weather this process is automatic or i have to call `setAlternateImage` to change it manually. 
This case how can I automatically produce the white copy of my image ? is there some tricks or best way to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using `imageNamed:`, you can simply append "Template" to your file name to get this behavior (e.g. "StatusItemTemplate.png"). Otherwise use `[myImage setTemplate:YES]`.